# Client-side fan out data structure

Tags: database, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I will implement my fan out model in Google's Firebase, but my question is only theoretical so the answer doesn't need to be in Firebase terms.

I am creating an app that I think should have a data structure similar to Tinder. The idea is only one post shows in your feed at a time; you then accept it or reject it and another one pops up and so on. My question is how exactly to structure the data so that it remains fast when the app scales up.

What I have right now is one node called "Posts" that contains every post that has ever been made. The app then queries for a post which is checked against the user Node of "viewedPosts" so that if the queried post has already been accepted/rejected by the user another one is queried until an unseen one is found. This obviously isn't a great solution because if there are a lot of posts, a query through them will be slow (especially if a lot of them have already been seen and the query has to be repeated multiple times).

I came across this article: [The Firebase Blog: Client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) which gave me the idea of creating a node inside each user which is "unseen posts" and every time a new post is uploaded by someone, to put it in the unseen folder for every user. This solves the problem on the side of the viewer, but to upload, one would have to download the list of all users in the app and then write to every single one of them.

So the question is, is there a middle ground between these which I can use to accurately do this?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Someone asked for my data structure:

```
{
"posts": {
    "jkldsahjfkds": {
        "title": "Simple Post",
        "description": "This is my first post",
        "numberOfImages": "2",
        "price": "14.99",
        "timestamp": "51782345",
        "postedBy": "-hjd673bbewi7n",
        "name": "Ryan Jacobs"
    }
    "-nisd7enskwes" : {...}
    "-asdjfhk7385i" : {...}
    "-sdfh49506ndk" : {...}
    }
"users": {
    "user1": {
        "postsViewed": {
            "-nisd7enskwes": 51784645,
            "-sdfh49506ndk": 51782329
        }
        "postsLiked": {
            "-sdfh49506ndk": 51782329
        }
        "userData": {
            "name": "Albert Jones",
            "bio": "Hi! Jow is everyone doing!?",
            "location": "London"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure, post the actual structure as JSON (as text, no screenshot) and your proposal. But do note that in NoSQL solutions, the data model mostly depends on your application's needs. So there is no single best way. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) to get more familiar with these concepts.

Comment: I have added the data structure in case someone finds it of use. @FrankvanPuffelen, thank you. My question is just a general one so it isn't so much about how my data is structured. The underlying question is whether there is a way of the person posting not having to write to every user's node and the viewer not having to query through the whole list of posts. I can't think of a possible solution, so I might have to have a backend server which gets sent an upload instruction and it is the server that writes to every user's profile and not the front end user.